# How to solve my project dependencies vulnerability (Webpack, Babel, React)

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, dependencies, babeljs

I have a React project using Babel and Webpack. Recently I realized that my webpack wasn't "hot loading" anymore when I make a change in my project files. (this cause me some trouble, anyhow)

I audited my npm dependencies and had 60 vulnerabilities with 9 high and 2 critical. I thought this should be taken care of.

Now, I tried to install the package that seems to broke things (using npm audit) but to no avail. I still got 31 vulnerabilities even after trying to install a different version of React Script.

Now, if I try to start my app, webpack doesn't compile saying "Cannot find module '@babel/plugin-bugfix-v8-spread-parameters-in-optional-chaining'"

I tried to install the Babel dependencies but every time a new one comes up. I know Babel just recently updated to 7.16 (October 31, 2021). Is this why my problems started?

How should I go about resolving all those dependencies issues? I feel it's a never ending instance of install a new packages that just break another one...

[image: npm audit]

[image: webpack compiling fail]
Package.json

```
{
  "name": "timerfrontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack serve",
    "create": "webpack -w",
    "build": "webpack -p"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.13.13",
    "@webpack-cli/serve": "^1.6.0",
    "ansi-html": "^0.0.7",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^5.2.6",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.65.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^5.2.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.6.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "2": "^3.0.0",
    "@apollo/link-context": "^2.0.0-beta.3",
    "@apollo/react-hooks": "^4.0.0",
    "@auth0/auth0-react": "^1.8.0",
    "@auth0/auth0-spa-js": "^1.16.1",
    "@babel/plugin-bugfix-safari-id-destructuring-collision-in-function-expression": "^7.16.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-static-block": "^7.16.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.16.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-class-static-block": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-export-namespace-from": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-logical-assignment-operators": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-private-property-in-object": "^7.14.5",
    "@graphql-tools/url-loader": "^6.10.1",
    "@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin": "^0.5.3",
    "@rollup/plugin-babel": "^5.3.0",
    "@webpack-cli/init": "^1.0.3",
    "acorn": "^8.6.0",
    "apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.6.6",
    "apollo-client": "^2.6.10",
    "apollo-link-context": "^1.0.20",
    "apollo-link-http": "^1.5.17",
    "apollo-server": "^2.24.1",
    "apollo-server-express": "^2.24.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.1",
    "browserslist": "^4.18.1",
    "chokidar": "^3.5.2",
    "dayjs": "^1.10.5",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "^3.1.1",
    "fetchql": "^3.0.0",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "fsevents": "^1.2.13",
    "graphql": "^15.5.0",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.12.4",
    "graphql-tools": "^7.0.5",
    "joi": "^17.5.0",
    "node": "^16.1.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-refresh": "^0.11.0",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "svg-url-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "tough-cookie": "^2.5.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.5.0"
  },
  "description": ""
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QUICK UPDATE

I made progress over my dependencies vulnerabilities. The main issue was a package that was interfering with the others. But I didn't clean my packages in a long time so it was impossible to know which one.

Here's my process:
(to check what needs to be updated)

```
npm oudated
```

(checking for dependencies that aren't used or duplicate another)

```
depcheck
```

I proceed to delete and update all relevant packages and my vulnerabilities dropped to one. (it was 60 before with 2 critical) Then, I used the "npm audit fix" for the the last one.

I still have issue with my babel configuration but that's sign my original problem was.....elsewhere.